# iPhone/iPad: Build code in snow leopard having release to App store issues.

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am sure, this question is related to programming as well. I have built an iPhone/iPad app using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 SDK. So, this app works for iOS 5, 4.x devices. But i have "Snow leopard 10.6.7" mac, not the Lion. When i want to upload this build to App store using "Application Loader", its not allowing, but the same build if i am uploading in Lion Mac based "Application Loader", its allowing to upload to the App store.

Is Snow leopard restricted to upload iOS 5 built binary to the App store? What could the reason and did anyone came across this issue? Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any errors or anything from Application Loader? It usually says what went wrong if it fails to upload.

Comment: OK..I can give about the errors..but are you saying it is possible to upload an iPhone binaray which is built using iOS 5.0 SDK, using Application Loader in Snow Leopard?

Comment: It should be. They make a version of Xcode with the iOS 5 SDK built for Snow Leopard. You may need to update your version, but it should work on either.

Answer (score 1):

There are separate downloads of Xcode for Lion and for Snow Leopard.  Download the right one from developer.apple.com.

Comment: I have Xcode separately installed for Snow leopard and lion. No issues on building the project. Thank you.